# Is there a type-mismatch mistake in John Hughes's definition of foldtree?

Tags: haskell, fold, type-mismatch, algebraic-data-types

John Hughes, in his famous article entitled [*Why Functional Programming Matters*](http://worrydream.com/refs/Hughes-WhyFunctionalProgrammingMatters.pdf), describes data types for lists and *ordered labelled trees*,

> ```
> listof * ::= Nil | Cons * (listof *)
> treeof * ::= Node * (listof (treeof *))
> ```

and a function called `foldtree`,

> ```
> foldtree f g a (Node label subtrees) =
>          f label (foldtree f g a subtrees)
>
> foldtree f g a (Cons subtree rest) =
>          g (foldtree f g a subtree) (foldtree f g a rest)
>
> foldtree f g a Nil = a
> ```

I've implemented those two data types in Haskell and I'm currently trying to implement `foldtree`,

```hs
data Listof a = Nil | Cons a (Listof a)
    deriving (Read, Show, Eq)

-- implementation of some list functions... (skipped)

data Treeof a = Node a (Listof (Treeof a))
    deriving (Read, Show, Eq)

foldtree f g a (Node label subtrees) = f label (foldtree f g a subtrees)
foldtree f g a (Cons subtree rest)   = g (foldtree f g a subtree) (foldtree f g a rest)
foldtree f g a Nil                   = a
```

but I'm getting type mismatches:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Treeof t’
            with actual type ‘Listof (Treeof t)’
Relevant bindings include
  subtrees :: Listof (Treeof t) (bound at whyFunMatters.hs:27:28)
  label :: t (bound at whyFunMatters.hs:27:22)
  f :: t -> t1 -> t1 (bound at whyFunMatters.hs:27:10)
  foldtree :: (t -> t1 -> t1)
              -> (t1 -> t1 -> t1) -> t1 -> Treeof t -> t1
    (bound at whyFunMatters.hs:27:1)
In the fourth argument of ‘foldtree’, namely ‘subtrees’
In the second argument of ‘f’, namely ‘(foldtree f g a subtrees)’
```

(etc.)

After thinking some more about Hughes (pseudo)implementation of `foldtree`, I'm not so sure I understand it, and those type mismatches now seem obvious to me. More specifically, the type of `foldtree`'s fourth argument doesn't seem consistent across the three patterns:

- in the first pattern, that argument has type `Treeof a`, whereas
- in the last two patterns, it has type `Listof (Treeof a)`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A proper definition should consist of a pair of mutually recursive functions, one for folding *trees* and one for folding *forests* (lists of trees):

```
foldtree :: (a -> c -> b) -> (b -> c -> c) -> c -> Treeof a -> b
foldtree f g a (Node label subtrees) = f label (foldforest f g a subtrees)

foldforest :: (a -> c -> b) -> (b -> c -> c) -> c -> Listof (Treeof a) -> c
foldforest f g a (Cons subtree rest) = g (foldtree f g a subtree) (foldforest f g a rest)
foldforest f g a Nil                 = a
```

I think the author has mistakenly combined two different (but closely related) functions together.  I suspect what the author wrote is not really Haskell but more of a Haskell-like pseudocode, so the code was just used to present the algorithm in an informal way.

Note that the paper seems to suggest it's Miranda, a predecessor of Haskell, but I can't confirm if this is legal Miranda code either.

Comment: I don't know Miranda either, but I'd be surprised if it allowed such a thing. I suspect the informal presentation hypothesis is closer to the truth than the mistaken combination, but you'd have to ask John Hughes (and if you have the chance to ask him questions, you might be better off asking him something more interesting).

Comment: It's not written in any particular functional language, and the exact code from the paper has not been through a compiler.  I've tried persuading John to update his paper with Haskell code, but he's too busy.  But if someone else did it, I'm sure he'd accept the contribution.

Comment: @augustss By the way, if you ever manage to persuade John to update his paper, there is a typo on page 4: `sum (Cons n list) = num + sum list`. Out of curiosity, what exactly did you mean by "if someone else did it"?

Comment: If someone else redid the paper with Haskell.

Comment: @augustss, formality issues aside, I'm much more confused that Hughes didn't come up with this one-liner instead: `foldtree f g a (Node label subtrees) = f label (foldr (g . foldtree f g a) a subtrees)`. No type issues there. Check out my answer below for details. Maybe Hughes would be so embarrassed about this mistake that he immediately wants to redo the paper himself :)

Answer (score 2):

Searching on Google I found the link https://gist.github.com/vu3rdd/14f10df24fbeffda09ae where the author informs that the document has been updated and is available at http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/whyfp.pdf.

Author John Hughes even apologizes for the examples not being on haskell!

> This paper dates from 1984, and circulated as a Chalmers memo for many
>   years. Slightly revised versions appeared in 1989 and 1990 as [Hug90]
>   and [Hug89]. This version is based on the original Chalmers memo nroff
>   source, lightly edited for LaTeX and to bring it closer to the
>   published versions, and with one or two errors corrected. Please
>   excuse the slightly oldfashioned type-setting, and the fact that the
>   examples are not in Haskell!

Below the corrections presented by the author...

```
redtree f g a (node label subtrees) =
    f label (redtree’ f g a subtrees)
redtree’ f g a (cons subtree rest) =
    g (redtree f g a subtree) (redtree’ f g a rest)
redtree’ f g a nil = a
```

Answer (score 1):

Rufflewind's answer is the most obvious way to fix the questionable definition of `foldtree` from Hughes' famous paper. Yet there is a much more concise and modular solution requiring only one line of code and reusing `foldr`. Scroll to the bottom of this post to see this definition. Keep on reading for some kind of derivation of the definition.

Compare Rufflewind's  definition of `foldforest`:

```
foldforest f g a (Cons subtree rest) = g (foldtree f g a subtree) (foldforest f g a rest)
foldforest f g a Nil                 = a
```

...with Hughes' (slightly changed) definition of `foldr` from the paper:

```
foldr f a (Cons e rest)              = f e (foldr f a rest)
foldr f a Nil                        = a
```

Don't they both look awfully similar? In fact the only difference is that in `foldforest` we apply `foldtree f g a` to `subtree` and (through recursion) to all the other elements in the list of subtrees before "merging" them with `g`. Can we define an operator that does this and can be passed to `foldr`?

Let's take a closer look at the core of `foldforest` where the actual work is done: `g (foldtree f g a subtree)`. Using function composition (defined in Hughes' paper as `(f . g) h = f (g h)`) we can express this part differently:

```
foldforest f g a (Cons subtree rest) = (g . foldtree f g a) subtree (foldforest f g a rest)
```

Now let's define `h = (g . foldtree f g a)` for brevity and pass a concrete list of subtrees to `foldforest` unfolding the recursion using our new notation:

```
foldforest f g a (Cons subtree1 (Cons subtree2 Nil)) 
                                     = h subtree1 (h subtree2 a)
```

What does it look like to unfold the recursion of a similar call to `foldr`?

```
foldr f a (Cons subtree1 (Cons subtree2 Nil))
                                     = f subtree1 (f subtree2 a)
```

It is now obvious that we were able to extract an operator from `foldforest` which we can pass to `foldr` along with a starting state `a` and a list of `Treeof`s. The complete definition of `foldtree`, maximizing modularity and conciseness, should therefor be:

```
foldtree f g a (Node label subtrees) = f label (foldr (g . foldtree f g a) a subtrees)
```